# Help proving convergence of this series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm interested in finding conditions about the convergence of a series. I have an increasing succession $\{a_n\}$.

The elements of $\{a_n\}$ are positive real numbers. I want to know the conditions where $$\sum_{n\gt1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{a_1a_2...a_n}$$ converge. 
I used the ratio test where i found that the series converges if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}\lt1$$
Are there are more conditions?

I would appreciate additional insight, or hints.

Comment: I don't understand why this is down-voted.  The OP has asked a legitimate question and explained what he has done so far.  Furthermore, what he did was correct.  How has he violated any condition of the site?

Comment: @saulspatz. I agree with you...................

Answer (score 2):

If all of the $a_n$ are $\le 1$ then the $n$th term doesn't go to $0$ and the series diverges.  Therefore, the condition you have found is necessary and sufficient.